# passing value to referencing table gives Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have two tables: `users` and `pics`. They both have a `pic_id` attribute except the `pics` table references the `pic_id` in the `users` table.

Inside my users table:
user_id: 15
password: test
age: 18
pic_id: 0

I am trying to insert a row into my `pics` table with the `pic_id` attribute equal to the `pic_id` value for user 15.

I am trying to do all of this in PHPMyAdmin and I am getting the `Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails` error.

I read that the reason this error happens is because the value the referencing table is looking for does not exist; however in my case I am sure it does.

Attached is my `users` and `pics` table relationship: [image: table relationship][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MkB6.png)

EDIT: Constraint Properties:

```
  CONSTRAINT `pics_ibfk_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`pic_id`)
    REFERENCES `db`.`users` (`pic_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Comment: please show us the properties of the constraint. thanks.

Comment: @t1t1an0 added it in

Comment: 1. check if both tables have the same data type for column `pic_id' 2. maybe the row you are pointing to in the `users` table is still uncommitted? 3. you might want to read this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566991/mysql-5-5-foreign-key-constraint-fails-when-foreign-key-exists

Comment: Which table did you define the FK constraint *on*? It should be `CONSTRAINT pics_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (pic_id) REFERENCES db.pics (pic_id)`. (I think.)